# Turn on a-gps on windows 7

Tags: windows-7

How do I turn on a-gps on windows 7, if my device has a-gps.
I searched on google and tried to find the option on control panel.

Comment: What is your hardware?

Comment: I have Acer Iconia Tab W500 with built-in a-gps